# Script to make 1 random layer visible within each group [Photoshop cc2018]

Tags: javascript, random, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to make a script that would at random select and show a single layer from all groups on Photoshop and export the result as a png.

I found this script here that seems to work:

```html
function Visible() {
  var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets; // loops through all groups
  for(var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++){
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible=true;
    var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;
    var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);
    groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;
    Save();
  }
  Revert();
}

function Save() {
  var outFolder = app.activeDocument; // psd name
  var outPath = outFolder.path;
  var fName = "PNG";   // define folder name
  var f = new Folder(outPath + "/" + fName);
  if ( ! f.exists ) {
    f.create()
  }
  var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName +"/" + "Pattern_" +  num + ".png");
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

function Revert(){
  var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
  var desc300 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref163 = new ActionReference();
  var idSnpS = charIDToTypeID( "SnpS" );
  ref163.putName( idSnpS, "test.psd" );
  desc300.putReference( idnull, ref163 );
  executeAction( idslct, desc300, DialogModes.NO );
}

var count = prompt("How many patterns you want","");
for (var x=0 ; x<count;x++){
  var num = x+1;
  Visible();
}
Share
```

Except it gives me an error 8800: General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.
Line: 36
-> executeAction( idslct, desc300, DialogModes.NO );

Is there smth I can do to make it work as that would greatly help speed up my work process.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what your PSD looks like, it's hard to tell. However, I think the code is failing on the revert function.

Try this instead:

```
function Revert()
{
  // =======================================================
  var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
  executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}
```